# Cannot access dir although user belongs in the group

Tags: permissions, directory, groups

I have a directory named `foo` that has the following permissions:

```
ls -dl foo
d---r-x---  3 foobar  staff  96 Sep  1 10:29 foo
```

While executing `groups` or `id` when logged in as `foobar` I get back a list of groups that contain `staff` and `gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff)` respectively. My understanding is that this means I'm a member of the `staff` group.

However when trying to do `ls foo/` I get back `Permission denied`.

I was under the impression that the `r-x` permissions will give me right to list the contents of the directory as well as read the files in it. Why isn't this the case? Any ideas?

Comment: most commands will stop evaluating permission as soon as one of the permission classes meets its criteria. For example, if I'm the owner of a file/directory, only the user class will be considered when calculating the effective user right.

Comment: best paste the first part too: The root user can read/write to any file and execute if any of the permission classes have the exec-bit set.

Comment: Thanks @bac0n. It seems that even if I log in as user `foobaz` that belongs to group `staff` I still cannot `ls` the directory.

Comment: Yes, the *group class* will not be considered or evaluated, because you are the owner (effectively stops the evaluation of the remaining classes: group and other), if you, e.g., were to log in as a different user you should be able to `ls`. The owner can always regain control of its own files, though. so, there is no reason to limit the owner from a security perspective.

Comment: Thanks @bac0n. If you write this as an answer I can then accept it. Thank you!